Tik-tok api signature hmac
I've been trying to get the tik tok shop api to work, but I ran into a problem at the signature stage. I caught myself completely not understanding this stage. I have adapted GO version to node js version, but I can't get what should be input, what params route should have, and where to put the result I get.
import crypto from 'crypto';

const secret = 'secret';

function generateSHA256(input, secret) {
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret);
    hmac.update(input);
    return hmac.digest('hex');
}


router.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const queries = req.query;

    let keys = Object.keys(queries);
    keys = keys.filter((key) => key !== 'sign' && key !== 'access_token');
    keys = keys.sort();

    let input = '';
    keys.forEach((key) => {
        input += key + queries[key];
    });

    input = req.path + input;

    const mediaType = req.headers['content-type'];
    if (mediaType !== 'multipart/form-data') {
        const body = req.body;
        input += body;
    }

    input = secret + input + secret;

    const sign = generateSHA256(input, secret);

    res.send(sign);


});


For starters: This needs to be based on the parameters of the API request you intend to make. Whereas your code looks like you are trying to calculate a signature for the parameters that your controller was invoked with ...?
